# Trouble reading excel file C#

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, streamreader

I need help. I made a form in C# that send an excel file, which is read and written in a div element after. The problem is the program writes wrong characters. I have tried to encode the output in UTF8, but the program returns something like this:

PK!?z??x [Content_Types].xml ?(???J?0????V?lDd?.?^???19]??$?ds{{O???Â?4?9??~I?o8^?:Y??????K?H?*3????9?g   a???@?6?l?]d?EZ(mQT??°v C?A(,B??8f?????,F?~? ??????q?G??????#?2g?Fv???9?RxPo?SRt?]??ZNJ?2o?A?????)?<\????;u$>Tp???p?4???(}??[?s?|}??PK!?U0#?L_rels/.rels ?(????N?0??H?C???nH???LH?!T?$????$@????Jc??????[???iTb/Nú(A?3b{?jx??V?b"gi??aW??l_x???b?????????#b4O??r??0Q?ah??e??=??P-????3{??Ä?C"$?i;?_???!?4jw??K? ?c?xJ????????\s*&   A@??M?b????2??yFRx7?"? E?2??&le?V[*I0M?????   ?3??[???z!db????????!g??:I??1???*@K/?A??+[WW?fN??Z??o?r??`|?jd?hT ???+;%`j?????z??p??V?g??Q?<????[k?>???s???4[?.?????Fm????? ???Fg??]??d??????z??P?hz?????s?%d??J??7j9|??l(?K???T-??? dX??YF&8??a??G?c?]???bx{?Y?C|????U??8?B?f?5???|????é?I?B?? ?º??z~???O?OQ?J???K?9? ?@\fU6C?=???C???!?> ? ?yn??? 'U,?8a??oaW)9???????HG?q?)?h??? ?M??2?l??H??A?[?s???1N?*???}O@?b??U|????!8]?{?x?>?????z???S??I&?T%0??SP?V?!????PK!???m?xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml??Mk?0???????liZ??X?1?qv%1??`?k??tz?M???z_y??y'~ &????,????????WR$??rI.??-?ujH0!?B?D?T?dZ?:e?A?J??k?46*ut5\?N???Nym?<???5?D?????4????]:?9?u\o?+??cDi?????? u?X?nt??=$'xoMA5e?S?AO5O?D1i>?,+?m?B>????s?,l?X?^???? ?????y??-?R'xB?m+jy??? j?q???MK|z?jzQ?j??d?Mg??1??4???^ullH?A=t?K??,+?m?B>????s?,l?X?^???? ?????y??-?R'xB?m+jy??? j?q???MK|z?jzQ?j??d?Mg??1??4???^ullH?A=t?K???iq???0(4|??h? ????h?????H?+??ejR]q?5"??6D??%????5n?a?B??????V?C?jG??MN?$6?"?U??^?'O?2?? ?h??zy#_??QNK1?@???y?PJ?d?=?????,??A?P  ?C?;?@???¹??????o(}???S?\ ??(?3\UK???%????#8?????Q??w?m????B??%TF?K???z???v'??r"S????&?2???ON+?_?&P\1??????'?Y??3P??\???La?? ?  ?.=zP%=o???(??+H?sH?Ep???m???-sm???`8 ???"?yY????/?J^?k?5?v???c?m?t?:F"}?????~\?h?W?Y???xr??pL\?] ??P???Ly?????O*???E[? ?-i?W?$?lEL????? ??? ???vp)?pU    G???Rq~?W5s?N???PK!r?VDxl/sharedStrings.xmll??n?0???Q?k??m*7HE? p?Y??#??RM???G???q?`?5??SN?U?gs????NC????3F??????!??/???@k??V???9???'9?z6?????qZc??H?y??A??4CO???Na?/?x??EuI?@?. L??( ????6I????????+??E6[O    i????f?dk@?lR?????Q?????y????9???H?gO˜o|?q?7*?x?XO?>?U-x]???L@?N7??t??K??&?x?o?????T?`????8qG??ka??N?F?B{? ?? ???PK!??H?H? xl/styles.xml??M??0?????#?M?I???d ?RH ?*??????i???v??=??k4=zg4r??J?N?X?U???#?r]pU%??>YGUA?V,?gf?c??Cl?Y??1??l????+Bl~d??????RILMElm-??$???H??  +??DR???A?eM?p??ca$??s???R???v7y??<7???MGtY?U?$K?4.?r?Qjh??U?*?K??G????NT?g?I?Zh?T?uE%?#6T??>????s??+?'9?????????GCu3*? ?????\d????]z?F? ?;0???8?z\i,X?@????N??=h??i\pZiE??????3!v??~?w?D???t?E??M}.&$2?=??x?-?g??????w??????A@?th?p\???Y???????~?Rv?D?J??|????72???v"?W????????Z?b??`D??   ??????>eQ??`????|? ??z??an??? ???Q??????????|@?[u?1T?@{?IB??U??@??8???:t:?=e??{??`l?&i?.F?O??????K??*s?)??????J???|o zd?K????eS???/%????s[x?+??" 1i_?g????????8e2?iFo??6s?6v?Y?O??????2?g_????PK!r?\?8docProps/app.xml ?(????n?0???????@V1?r?I{?d:?H????f?m#?????H??????? Z??S,?tRH???m)7?n?K?dceC?P???3o??UN d?-"?rG?,?B????  ??:?%N?V????;?!???;G?XAu?<??q??kM??:>|?6?C??,??w9a?I|<:Z?E?tkp???d ??^;??Mm?V??^???>??--Zp??@???6??E?pJ???m$?????C???2}?(*????!i?}???#???y???ucg0?pM????+?????1x?0`*P?c?g?n???9?*????????l?%8o????;???:?^??s?L?w6n?:??+to?i?fz;)?_?????????PK!?(W??xl/calcChain.xmlt?? ?0????^????|}???m???7"?M _??9)?O??}h???3`h??Z[?]/?????v?0???N %?:7???l???8?A#??uhirw??H??y?

My code behind is the next:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];

if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0 && (Path.GetExtension(file.FileName) == ".xlsx" || Path.GetExtension(file.FileName) == ".xls"))
        {
            StreamReader reader = null;
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            string value = "";

            CultureInfo cultureSp;
            Encoding encodingSp;
            cultureSp = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
            encodingSp = Encoding.GetEncoding(cultureSp.TextInfo.ANSICodePage);

            using (reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))
            {
                while ((value = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    data.AppendLine(value); 
                }
            }
            escribirExcel.InnerHtml = encodingSp.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data.ToString()));

        }
        else
            escribirExcel.InnerHtml = "ERROR";

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to convert an Excel file to text? Do you only want a specific cell or range or are you trying to see the XML?

Comment: what you want to do with your excel file?

Comment: I want to read an excel file and then write its info in a div tag. I had already solved my question.